# AcceptsReturn on TextBox not functioning correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple search field on a form that is set as multiline (which I understand is the only way to change a text box's height) and has the flag AcceptsReturn set to false.

However, when I press enter within that control, instead of it activating the default button as it should, it puts in a return character.

Now, I've also attempted using the KeyPress event to check if the Enter key has been pressed to activate the search-button click function in the hope that it would override this return behaviour - but it hasn't. Now it just runs the search AND inserts a return character.

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 (although this problem seemed to be present in 2008 too before I converted it) and C# .NET 2.0. Any solutions?

Comment: Please don't prefi your titles with "C# .NET" and such. That's what the tags are for. Also, I presume this is Windows Forms?

Comment: I just attempted to duplicate your issue with no success.  I created a new form with a button and a text box(multiline)  I set the textbox.acceptreturn to false. and I set the forms accept button to button1(my button)   the button click event fired a messagebox.  When I typed something and pressed enter it fired the messagebox and did not add a return character to the textbox.  Are you sure you set the Forms accept button

Comment: If anyone is tempted enough, you can download the source via Git at github.com/CJxD/CoreView.
It could just be a bug in my program - but there's no way I'm making the forms all over again!

Comment: Ah, @K'Leg, that could well be it. I set the form's accept button to a dummy button (as there are many search boxes on this form), and it stopped the Return behaviour.

Comment: I gotta start putting these comments as answers  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form has a property called *AcceptButton*.  Is that pointing to the button you are calling the *default button*?

I just wrote a little test and it seems to work for me.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. For my particular case, I can set the main form's accept button programmatically when I enter a particular search bar. Now it works properly!

Comment: Note how that stops working when you set AcceptsReturn to true.  Which is what the property really does.  You got the return in the text because you forgot e.SuppressKeyPress = e.Handled = true;

Answer (score 7):

I see that an answer has already been posted, which mentions the AcceptButton property, but I figure I would state more clearly *why* that's necessary: quoth [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx), on AcceptsReturn, "If there is no default button for the form, the ENTER key will always create a new line of text in the control, regardless of the value of this property." (I just tried it out on a dummy form - by "default button", they did in fact mean the form's AcceptButton property. With one set, the value of AcceptsReturn made a difference; without one, it had no effect.)

As for KeyPress, while that is obviously not the best way in this case, I have had to use tricks like that in the past - did you remember to set e.Handled to true in the case that you handled the event yourself?

Comment: Thanks on the e.Handled tip, I didn't even know this existed!