# Why am I getting an extraneous carriage return in a multi-line text box?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a strange bug occurring in a Winforms application, with a multi-line textbox. When I change the text of the textbox, I am getting an extra line break. The positioning of this line break varies. For example, if I do this:

```
someTextBox.Clear()
someTextBox.Text = someOtherObject.SomeTextProperty
```

Then I get the extra line break at the end of the text. However, If I don't call clear first, using the same value for SomeTextProperty, I get the line break at the beginning. However, if I just use a test string like "TEST", I get the line break at the beginning of the text, whether or not I call Clear() first. And If I use AppendText(), I get the line break inserted at the end in all cases.

Can anyone explain where these extraneous line breaks/carriage returns are coming from, and why their positioning sometimes changes?

Comment: Try setting the `.Lines()` property instead of `.Text`. (Pass it an array of strings if you are sending multi-line text or pass a single-line string to `.Lines(0)`.) See if this gives you different results.

Comment: May I ask how you figure out having an extra line-break ? What I mean is how do you inspect the value of `someTextBox.Text` ?

Comment: @Josh, per MSDN documents, Lines is the correct property to work with on a multi-line text box, not Text.  You should make that an answer.  See remarks at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6w057xy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hmm.. This hasn't helped. If I first clear the textbox, I then can't assign to textBox.Line(0), gives an Index Out Of Range Exception (of course). However if I do textBox.Lines = new String() { otherObject.TextProperty }, I am STILL getting an empty line at the start! :(

Comment: @Luc Morin, I can visually see that the text has been bumped down and has an empty line above it where there should be none. However, this doesn't actually tie up with what I'm seeing when I look in the Lines collection.

Comment: Ok, and can you confirm that the spurious linefeed is not coming from `someOtherObject.SomeTextProperty` ?

Comment: Yes, because I have also seen the same behaviour using just "TEST" instead of accessing the other property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503405/acceptsreturn-on-textbox-not-functioning-correctly). This is perhaps my fault for not fully explaining the situation. But I was triggering an event on pressing enter within the TextBox, and had the Textbox's AcceptsReturn property set to false. I was expecting the event to trigger with no carriage return in the box, hence my confusion at the carriage return. But according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx), if the form doesn't have a default OK button, you'll still get a carriage return, unless you set e.SuppressKeyPress in the event handler. Doing so prevents the extra carriage return appearing. However, I am *still* confused as to why, after setting `textbox.Lines = New String() { "TEST" }`, the carriage return remains. This seems like a bug to me.

edit: As pointed out in the comments by Josh, the carriage return was most likely being inserted after the event had been handled, and the text in the textbox had been updated.

Comment: More than likely it had to do with where you set the property (especially if it was the key press event you mentioned). I was unable to duplicate anything like your problem when I posted my answer. My code was in a button click event.

Comment: Good point, maybe the carriage return was being inserted after the event was handled. To easily reproduce, create a new form with a multiline text box, AcceptsReturn set false. Add a KeyDown event handler to the textbox like this:

If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
    textBox.Lines = new String() { "TEST" }
End If

Run, type some text in the box and press enter. You'll see it clear and you'll see "TEST" on the second line of the textbox. If you add e.SuppresKeyPress = True, you won't see it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.Lines()` property instead of `.Text`. (See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.100).aspx).)

You do not need to use `.Clear`; instead, simply make sure the array you are passing does not contain any unwanted empty strings, as these will translate to empty lines.

Some example code:

```
'Set lines
Dim myLines As String() = {"Hello.", _
                         "My name is Inigo Montoya.", _
                         "", _
                         "You killed my father.", _
                         "Prepare to die."}
someTextBox.Lines = myLines

'Get lines
MsgBox(Join(someTextBox.Lines, vbCrLf))
```

I have tested the above successfully. If you're still having problems, post the code where you set the value (using `someOtherObject.SomeTextProperty`) or where you read the values, because the problem is likely there.

Comment: using someTextBox.Lines = New String() {"TEST"}, I am STILL seeing this issue. I suspect it's a rendering issue, because when I inspect the contents of Lines, I can see that the array is of size 1 and only contains "TEST". Yet when I click into the textbox (which is sized to only look 1 line high), and press the up arrow key, the cursor jumps up to a single empty line above "TEST". I'm baffled.

Comment: @chipples, can I see your full code? My email is in my profile if it's too much to post here.

Comment: OK, I'm emailed it to you.